# validate data in a textbox in wpf from validation functions

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

well I have the following problem I try to validate the RUC of the provider of my country, the question is that I have implemented the validation functions which are the following:

ID validation function

```
 public class Verifica_Identificacion
{
    internal static bool VerificaIdentificacion(string identificacion)
    {
        bool estado = false;
        char[] valced = new char[13];
        int provincia;
        if (identificacion.Length >= 10)
        {
            valced = identificacion.Trim().ToCharArray();
            provincia = int.Parse((valced[0].ToString() + valced[1].ToString()));
            if (provincia > 0 && provincia < 25)
            {
                if (int.Parse(valced[2].ToString()) < 6)
                {
                    estado = VC.VerificaCedula(valced);
                }
                else if (int.Parse(valced[2].ToString()) == 6)
                {
                    estado = VSP.VerificaSectorPublico(valced);
                }
                else if (int.Parse(valced[2].ToString()) == 9)
                {

                    estado = VPJ.VerificaPersonaJuridica(valced);
                }
            }
        }
        return estado;
    }
}
```

This function depends on other validations that are carried out independently because there are some types of RUC, below the other three functions are shown

ID verification

```
public class VC
{
    public static bool VerificaCedula(char[] validarCedula)
    {
        int aux = 0, par = 0, impar = 0, verifi;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i += 2)
        {
            aux = 2 * int.Parse(validarCedula[i].ToString());
            if (aux > 9)
                aux -= 9;
            par += aux;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 9; i += 2)
        {
            impar += int.Parse(validarCedula[i].ToString());
        }

        aux = par + impar;
        if (aux % 10 != 0)
        {
            verifi = 10 - (aux % 10);
        }
        else
            verifi = 0;
        if (verifi == int.Parse(validarCedula[9].ToString()))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

public sector verification

```
public class VSP
{
    public static bool VerificaSectorPublico(char[] validarCedula)
    {
        int aux = 0, prod, veri;
        veri = int.Parse(validarCedula[9].ToString()) + int.Parse(validarCedula[10].ToString()) + int.Parse(validarCedula[11].ToString()) + int.Parse(validarCedula[12].ToString());
        if (veri > 0)
        {
            int[] coeficiente = new int[8] { 3, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                prod = int.Parse(validarCedula[i].ToString()) * coeficiente[i];
                aux += prod;
            }

            if (aux % 11 == 0)
            {
                veri = 0;
            }
            else if (aux % 11 == 1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                aux = aux % 11;
                veri = 11 - aux;
            }

            if (veri == int.Parse(validarCedula[8].ToString()))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

verification of legal person

```
public class VPJ
{
    public static bool VerificaPersonaJuridica(char[] validarCedula)
    {
        int aux = 0, prod, veri;
        veri = int.Parse(validarCedula[10].ToString()) + int.Parse(validarCedula[11].ToString()) + int.Parse(validarCedula[12].ToString());
        if (veri > 0)
        {
            int[] coeficiente = new int[9] { 4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                prod = int.Parse(validarCedula[i].ToString()) * coeficiente[i];
                aux += prod;
            }
            if (aux % 11 == 0)
            {
                veri = 0;
            }
            else if (aux % 11 == 1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                aux = aux % 11;
                veri = 11 - aux;
            }

            if (veri == int.Parse(validarCedula[9].ToString()))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like is to use the "ID validation function" in a textbox that accepts the RUC as input so far the data entry and that is stored in the database I did it as follows, however, as you can see I can only enter the string of the ruc without the respective validation. I would like a help to use my validation function at the time of entering the ruc and save it, if the entry was correct, the message "Provider stored correctly" appears and if it was not entered successfully, exit the message "Wrong RUC re-enter data"

data entry code from stored procedure (data layer)

```
  public void Insertar(string NombreProveedor, string rucProveedor)
    {
        comando.Connection = con.AbrirConexion();
        comando.CommandText = "IngresarProveedor";
        comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NombreProveedor", NombreProveedor);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rucProveedor", rucProveedor);
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        comando.Parameters.Clear();
        con.CerrarConexion();

    }
```

data entry code (business cape)

```
private CD_RUC proveedor_cd = new CD_RUC();
    public void InsertarProv(string NombreProveedor, string rucProveedor)
    {
        proveedor_cd.Insertar(NombreProveedor, rucProveedor);

    }
```

save button settings (presentation layer)

```
 private void btn_Guardar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        proveedorcn NPro = new proveedorcn();
        NPro.InsertarProv(TXT_Nombre_Proveedor_P.Text, TXT_RUC.Text);
        MessageBox.Show("Proveedor Ingresado Correctamente");
    }
```

Comment: Your code is very far from anything which you'd implement inotifydataerrorinfo on. Why not just call your methods in the button click handler?

Comment: It is precisely that part that gives me problems. I would like to call the validation method for the ruc and that I get the error messages. I would like some help with that part, how would I call my function to validate my string in the textbox?

Comment: You get what error messages originating from which line of your code when you do what with what code.

Comment: Your question is slightly confusing to me. The way I understood the question, the solution is at your hands. You should call `Verifica_Identificacion.VerificaIdentificacion` from your save button handler. Note that in a more serious solution you would implement the validation logic and data access in the view model. See MVVM pattern. A view model class would preferably implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo`. This way WPF supports an elegant way to display error messages out of the box - less aggressive than showing a `MessageBox`.